# Is there anyway to use variables in text fields?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there anyway to use variables in text fields?

For example i have a variable for my file directory `STRDIR` and default setted to workbooth path

Is there any way to user can write to textbox(name TextBox1) in VBA like that {STRDIR}/theirfilename.txt and after that i plan to see when i `Debug.Print TextBox1.Value` i would like to see result as `STRDIR + "theirfilename.txt"`

Is it possible to use like that ? Regards.

Comment: You can use `Replace("{STRDIR}", STRDIR)` but there's no automatic process for variable substitution.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks. This is the answer guys i couldn't voted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Debug.Print Replace(Textbox1.Value, "{STRDIR}", STRDIR)
```

but there's no automatic process for variable substitution

Comment: there's only problem with replacing in Value property. `Replace(Textbox1.Value, STDIR)`. Is there any possible way to apply it on `Textbox1.Value`

Comment: Sorry my bad - I missed the textbox part - see my update

Answer (score 0):

### Use `&` for concatenating strings and string-variables.

`+` sometimes works with strings in VBA but should be reserved for addition.

---

Unless you literally want to display the *name* of the variable, like your example:

```
`STRDIR + "theirfilename.txt"`
```

..which means you're looking for a function to provide the same output as this:

```
Debug.Print "STRDIR + ""theirfilename.txt"""
```

...but I doubt that's what you mean.

Comment: thanks for your help dude. I mean like Tim's answer.